# Unclear Complex Regular expression

Tags: regex

I'm new to Regular Expressions and has stumbled upon an expression I do not really understand. 
The expression is:

```
.*[^0-9](?P<ref>[0-9]{3})[^0-9].*
```

and I think I understand the first part and the last part, but the part within parenthesis eludes me. I would be most grateful for an explanation or some links where I could find help with this.
Thanks.

Comment: For the links request there are many tools online to explain your regex: see http://regex101.com/r/dW2uF4 for example. Also note that the language used is important as multiple regex flavors are out there

Answer (score 3):

The part within parentheses is a [named capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) that matches exactly three digits (and lets that group be referenced by the name `ref`). This feature was added because in very long, complex expressions, it's much clearer to used named groups than the usual numbered groups (which requires counting parentheses to see which group is which).

Exactly how the named capture referencing is done depends on the regular expression library and/or language being used. For example, in Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> match = re.search(r'.*[^0-9](?P<ref>[0-9]{3})[^0-9].*', 'a234b')
>>> match.group('ref')
'234'
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a short graphical explanation for your expression:

```
.*[^0-9](?P<ref>[0-9]{3})[^0-9].*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/a_ZjRLDL0a-GzI5Z)

In words:

- `.*` matches any number of any chars
- `[^0-9]` matches one char, that is not a number
- `(?P<ref>[0-9]{3})` matches a group of three numbers and gives the group in the result the name *ref*
- `[^0-9]` ... obvious
- `.*` ... obvious